# How to change X-Frame-Options" from DENY to SAMEORIGIN

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with ASP.NET. Due to security reasons I hadto set **X-Frame-Options** to **DENY** in Web.Config. But the site contains some iframes. So, I have to change the **X-Frame-Options** to **SAMEORIGIN** from time to time.

In the `Page_PreRender` event I have written the following code:

````
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
```

But I still get the DENY option from the web config.

Please, any ideas?
````

Comment: what in your webconfig are you using to set it? iirc asp.net doesn't set those by default

Comment: <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42168501/970074

Depending on your project, you'll likely want to look at another location to insert the "DENY" instead of in the web.config so that you can override it when necessary with "SAMEORIGIN".  Action filters would be a good place to do this if you're using MVC.

Comment: Thank you. I solved by using Application_PreSendRequestHeaders event in Global.asax.cs. I'm not using web.config for X-Frame-Options header.